# list.setAdapter(new ApplistAdapter() has null pointer exception

Tags: android, json, listview

i am trying to accept some values from server using json and display it in a custom list.. the problem i am facing is after accepting the values from server and decoding the values when the values are added to array list i am getting this error...

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.quinoid.pushnotification, PID: 1700
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.quinoid.patient.MainActivity$JSONParse.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:207)
at com.quinoid.patient.MainActivity$JSONParse.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**my json class**

```
    private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
 DocGetSet DGS = new DocGetSet();   
 private ProgressDialog dialog;

@Override
   protected void onPreExecute() {
       super.onPreExecute();

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait");
        dialog.setTitle("Connecting server");
        dialog.show();
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
}

@Override
   protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

    JSONData jParser = new JSONData();

    String url = "http://projects.quin.com/Chai/Connect/json/SearchingRange.php?range=5&devicetoken=swghfghjgh";
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
    return json;
}
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
    dialog.cancel();
     try {
            // Getting JSON Array from URL
            android = json.getJSONArray(TAG_TITLE);

            for (int i = 0; i < android.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = android.getJSONObject(i);


                // Storing  JSON item in a Variable

                DGS.setPhoto(c.getString(TAG_IMAGE)); getting values here
                DGS.setName(c.getString(TAG_NAME));   getting values here
                DGS.setId(c.getString(TAG_ID));       getting values here  

                DGS.setDistance(c.getString(TAG_DISTANCE));  getting values here                

                //new DownloadTask().execute(DGS.getPhoto());

                mylist.add(DGS);


     -----------getting error here--------------------
                list.setAdapter(new ApplistAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                        mylist));
            }




    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


 }
}
```

so what is wrong ?? i dont get it...

**MainActivity.java**

```
  public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

private static final String TAG_TITLE = "SearchingDoctors";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "Doctorsname";
private static final String TAG_SPECIALIZATION = "Specialization";          
private static final String TAG_IMAGE = "ProfilePicture";
private static final String TAG_ID = "DoctorsId";
private static final String TAG_DISTANCE = "distance";


Spinner spin;
List<String> Speciality;
ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter1;

String DeviceToken,speciality;
int progress = 0;

ArrayList<DocGetSet> mylist = new ArrayList<DocGetSet>();

ListView list;

JSONParser json = new JSONParser();
JSONArray android = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent myintent = getIntent();
    DeviceToken = myintent.getStringExtra("DeviceToken");



    //Connection detector
    ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
    // Alert dialog manager
    AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();
    // Check if Internet present
    if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
        // Internet Connection is not present
        alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this,
                "Internet Connection Error",
                "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
        // stop executing code by return
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        new JSONParse().execute();
    }

    main();
}


protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String name = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvDoctorName)).getText().toString();
    Toast.makeText(this, "You have selected : " + " " +name , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SelectedDoctor.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("id", id);
    startActivity(myIntent);
}



private void main() {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
    spin = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    //SpinnerValues();
    final TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new  OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            textView.setText(""+progress+" Km");
            speciality = spin.getSelectedItem().toString();

            ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
            // Alert dialog manager
            AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();
            // Check if Internet present
            if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
                // Internet Connection is not present
                alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this,
                        "Internet Connection Error",
                        "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
                // stop executing code by return
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                new JSONParse().execute();
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progresValue, boolean fromUser) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             progress = progresValue;
             textView.setText(""+progress+" Km");
        }
    });

 }



private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
 DocGetSet DGS = new DocGetSet();   
 private ProgressDialog dialog;

@Override
   protected void onPreExecute() {
       super.onPreExecute();

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait");
        dialog.setTitle("Connecting server");
        dialog.show();
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
}

@Override
   protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

    JSONData jParser = new JSONData();

    String url = "http://projects.quin.com/Chai/Connect/json/SearchingRange.php?range=5&devicetoken=swghfghjgh";

    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
    return json;
}
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
    dialog.cancel();
     try {
            // Getting JSON Array from URL
            android = json.getJSONArray(TAG_TITLE);

            for (int i = 0; i < android.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = android.getJSONObject(i);


                // Storing  JSON item in a Variable

                DGS.setPhoto(c.getString(TAG_IMAGE));
                DGS.setName(c.getString(TAG_NAME));
                DGS.setId(c.getString(TAG_ID));
                //DGS.setSpecialization(c.getString(TAG_SPECIALIZATION));
                DGS.setDistance(c.getString(TAG_DISTANCE));                 

                //new DownloadTask().execute(DGS.getPhoto());

                mylist.add(DGS);
                list.setAdapter(new ApplistAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                        mylist));
            }




    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


   }
 }

 class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
     private ProgressDialog dialog;
     DocGetSet DGS = new DocGetSet();       
        @Override
           protected void onPreExecute() {
               super.onPreExecute();

                dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                dialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait");
                dialog.setTitle("Connecting server");
                dialog.show();
                dialog.setCancelable(false);

        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            String url = params[0];
            Bitmap photo;
            JSONPhotoData PhotoData = new JSONPhotoData();
            photo = PhotoData.getJSONPhotoFromUrl(url);
            return photo;

        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
            dialog.cancel();
           // DGS.setImage(bitmap);              
        }
    }

 private class ApplistAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        Context mycon;
        LayoutInflater inflater;
        ArrayList<DocGetSet> data;

        public ApplistAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<DocGetSet> mylist) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            mycon = context;
            data = mylist;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) mycon
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return data.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return data.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View v = convertView;
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (v == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
                holder.DocName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvDoctorName);
                holder.Distance = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tVDistance);
                //holder.Specialization = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tVSpecialization);
                holder.id  = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tVDoctorID);
                //holder.CimageView = (CircularImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                v.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
            }
            holder.DocName.setText(data.get(position).getName());
            holder.Distance.setText(data.get(position).getDistance());
        //  holder.Specialization.setText(data.get(position).getSpecialization());
            holder.id.setText(data.get(position).getId());
            //holder.CimageView.setImageBitmap(data.get(position).getImage());

            return v;
        }

        private class ViewHolder {

            public TextView DocName;

            public TextView Distance;

            //public TextView Specialization;

            public TextView id;

        //  public CircularImageView CimageView;


        }

    }

 }
```

Comment: where is list initialized and to which layout it belongs to?

Comment: json class is part of a bigger class.. i will post it.. my bad..

Comment: looks like list is null.  Sure the intialization is right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is **`NullPointerException`**...
Means You Are using object that is NULL......

There is problem with your **ListView** object..

initialize list before using it by

```
list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.yourlistviewname);
```

and then use it...

another thing with your code is that......
**Set list adapter outside of for loop...**

```
for(){....

}
list.setAdapter(new ApplistAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                        mylist));
```

put this code after your for loop ends..

hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

have you initialise "list" object

if not, create it

list = findViewById(R.id.....);

Answer (score 1):

First thing is that you have just declared your `ListView` not initialized.

```
ListView list;
```

So you need to initialize it on `main()` method. Like,

```
list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.yourlistviewname);
```

and also call your `main()` method before your `AsyncTask` been executed.

Another thing is that just set your adapter class out of your for loop.

```
list.setAdapter(new ApplistAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                    mylist));
```